# Changes to introduction missing from activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, activity-tab, documentation-intro

Changes to introduction sections (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/115564)) do not appear in the tag's [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql?tab=activity).

The only place they could be found is in [the topic's revision log](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/revisions/1002), but that makes it much harder to audit what the robo-reviewers have inflicted on the topic.

Comment: Wow, you are the sole reason that entire section is not a complete disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that got missed when we rolled out the Introduction section. I pushed a fix, so these changes should start showing up as expected as of the next build.